# Django Model not defined

Tags: python, django

I've been working on some views and using a model for like a week now and there was no issues until now: I did not change anything but add a new field to the model, and now `myModel.objects.create()` gives me a name is not defined error. I have the model imported and as I said, I've been working on this for a week and I created several models using the exact same code.

models:

```
class Prescription(models.Model):
    prescription_id = models.CharField(max_length=26, default=prescription_id, editable=False, unique=True) # THIS IS THE FIELD I ADDED BEFORE HAVING THIS ERROR
    appointment = models.ForeignKey('booking.Appointment', on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True, blank=True)
    doctor = models.ForeignKey('core.Doctor', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    patient = models.ForeignKey('core.Patient', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    overriden_date = models.DateField(null=True, blank=True)
    control = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    control_date = models.DateField(null=True, blank=True)
    send_email = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    posted = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = "Ordonnance"
        verbose_name_plural = "Ordonnances"

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.id)


class PrescriptionElement(models.Model):
    prescription = models.ForeignKey('Prescription', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    drug = models.ForeignKey(Drug, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    custom = models.CharField("Elément", max_length=25, null=True, blank=True)
    dosage = models.CharField(max_length=45, null=True, blank=True)
    posologie = models.CharField(max_length=256, null=True, blank=True)
    duration = models.CharField("Durée", max_length=15, null=True, blank=True)
```

views:

```
PrescriptionElement.objects.create(prescription=prescription, drug=listemedicament, custom=medicament, dosage=dosage, posologie=posologie, duration=duree)
```

error:

```
name 'PrescriptionElement' is not defined
```

Comment: You wouldn't get a NameError if the model was imported into the module where the error is raised. Without seeing the full file contents it's not possible to help

Comment: I have from .models import * in the file, and I am able to user other models in the same file. Only PrescriptionElement isn't working. I tried from .models import PrescriptionElement and it gives me a Circular Import error (the worst error I've experienced in Django in 9 years)

Comment: File "D:\Toubib\toubibv3\toubib-v3\dossiermedical\utils.py", line 7, in <module>
    from .models import PrescriptionElement as _pe
ImportError: cannot import name 'PrescriptionElement' from partially initialized module 'dossiermedical.models' (most likely due to a circular import) (D:\Toubib\toubibv3\toubib-v3\dossiermedical\models.py)

Comment: Can you add the full traceback to the question? The circular import is the issue. Your utils file and the models file don't import from each other do they?

Comment: They do, I remember another change I made besides adding a new field is that I moved 2 helper functions from project.utils to currentapp.utils and now they are importing from each other, it's fixed now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed the issue by removing any circular relation between multiple files. Circular Imports are the one problem causing this. The prescription_id default value was defined in a file called utils.py, and in utils.py there are some functions inheritting models from the models.py file. Removing this circular relationship fixes this issue.

Also, using this format to defined ForeignKeys ('booking.Appointment') is the better choice to avoir importing.